# How to add dependencies for my python code on Amazon EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

-I am successfully logged into my Virtual Machine and I have uploaded my files to the AWS as well (Amazon EC2). What I wish to do is execute my python code on the server but it says that the dependencies are not installed. When I run a pip install command, it returns the following error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/apiclient

How do I fix this? Is it even possible to install packages using pip? If yes, how?

Comment: pip install --user ec2-user xyz, or sudo pip install xyz

Answer (score 0):

Run command with sudo.

```
sudo pip install <pkg_name>
```

OR

install it using --user option which installs the package only for the current user and not for all

```
pip install <pkg_name> --user
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you logged in as ec2-user. Logged in user should have privileges to run commands or you have to log in as root.

if you're an ec2-user, then `sudo su -` switches to root user.

```
pip install <your_package_name>
```

If you don't want to run as a root, give the user access to run packages, proceed to step 2.

If you don't have a user, I recommend you to create a new user and then to Group wheel.

```
sudo su -
```

Step 1: As a root user, give the below commands.

```
adduser [username]
passwd [username]
:retype above passwd
```

Step 2: Add this user to run all commands,

```
visudo
```

Remove comment from line after "Allows people in group wheel to run all commands"
Save, exit vi.

```
usermod -Gwheel [username]
```

Now, the new user can also install pip packages.